# setInterval doesn't work correctly after first time Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, setinterval

I have the following code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
global.count =  0;

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('CONNECTED');

    socket.on('message', function(msg){

        var intVal = setInterval(function(){
            global.count = 0;
        },3000);

        console.log(global.count);

        if(global.count == 4){
            io.emit('freezeEvent');
            global.count = 0;
        }
        else{
            global.count++;
            io.emit('message',msg);
            clearInterval(intVal);
        }
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('DISCONNECTED');
    });
});

server.listen(3000);
```

With this code I'm trying to check if the user tries to send more than 4 messages in an interval of 3 seconds. I have the `global.count` variable, and each time a message is sent, I increment it by one. Every 3 seconds my `setInterval`  function makes the value of `count` 0, so it resets. Before the message is sent I check if the count is 4. If it is, then I fire the `freezeEvent`. In my front-end I have the following code, which disables the input for 5 seconds if the `freezeEvent` is fired:

```
$(function () {

    var socket = io('socket.loc:3000');

    socket.on('connect', function () {

        socket.on('freezeEvent', function(){

            $('.inp').attr("disabled", true);

            setTimeout(function(){ 
                $('.inp').attr("disabled",false);               
            }, 5000);
        });

    });
});
```

First time I run the code, my input becomes disabled after 4 messages, but the `count` never resets to 0. After the input becomes enabled, the `count` completely messes up. Here's what I got after first time when I console logged the `count`:

```
4
0
0
1
2
3
4
0
0
1
0
1
2
3
4
```

Can you please tell me what causes this and how can it be fixed?

**UPDATE**

I have changed my back-end code to the following and the counter doesn't mess up anymore. It always goes from 0 to 4. But the problem that remains is that it still doesn't reset after every 3 seconds. Here's my code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
global.count =  0;

global.intVal = setInterval(function(){
    global.count = 0;
},3000);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('CONNECTED');

    socket.on('message', function(msg){

        console.log(global.count);

        if(global.count == 4){
            io.emit('freezeEvent');
            global.count = 0;
        }
        else{
            global.count++;
            io.emit('message',msg);
            clearInterval(global.intVal);
        }
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('DISCONNECTED');
    });
});

server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Every message you create a new interval and lose access to it as soon as message processing is complete.

Comment: Should I create it after the connection is established? Also am I doing clearInterval in the right place?

Comment: your setInterval should be global not local

Comment: You need a single timer that resets the message count every n second, and when you send a message you check that count. Noting that there are throttling libraries that'll do this work for you.

Comment: I have changed the code and make the setInterval global. Now the counter doesn't mess up and always goes from 0 to 4, but it still doesn't reset every 3 seconds. I will add the changed code to the question, so please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the problem is

```
if(global.count == 4){
    io.emit('freezeEvent');
    global.count = 0;
}
else{
    global.count++;
    io.emit('message',msg);
    clearInterval(intVal);
}
```

you remove interval if global.count less than 4 so it didn't work for first [0-3] values

Another one thing: your global.count is one for each connection?

Comment: maybe better to use setTimeout and make global.count equal 0 once without clearing interval and so on?

Comment: Totally forgot about that. Removed the `clearInterval` and now it works, thanks!